# How to access Spring properties from an entity?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring app, that pushes data in an s3 bucket.

```
public class Ebook implements Serializable {

    @Column(name= "cover_path", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private String coverPath;

    private String coverDownloadUrl; 

   @Value("${aws.cloudfront.region}")
   private String awsCloudFrontDns; 

    @PostLoad
    public void init(){
        // I want to access the property here
        System.out.println("PostConstruct");
        String coverDownloadUrl = "https://"+awsCloudFrontDns+"/"+coverPath;
    }
```

When a data is pushed, let's say my cover here, I get the key `1/test-folder/mycover.jpg` which is the important part of the future http URL of the data.

When I read the data from database, I enter inside `@PostLoad` method and I want construct the complete URL using the cloudfront value. This value changes frequently so we don't want to save hardly in the database.

How could I do to construct my full path just after reading the data in database?

The only way to do this is to use a service that update the data after using repository to read it? For readbyId it can be a good solution, but for reading list or using other jpa methods, this solutions won't work because I have each time to create a dedicated service for the update.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look good for Entity to depend on property.

How about EntityListener.

```
@Component
public class EbookEntityListener {

 @Value("${aws.cloudfront.region}")
 private String awsCloudFrontDns; 

 @PostLoad 
 void postload(Ebook entity) { entity.updateDns(awsCloudFrontDns); }
}
```

I recommend trying this way  :)